# Help me translate Windows 10 SMBv2 credentials into to Ubuntu 18.10 equivalent

Tags: 18.10

I have an Windows 10 v1809 PC (which I'll just call Windows10PC) that has an SMBv2 folder (SMBv2Folder) shared to my home LAN (i.e. NOT a domain). From a Windows 10 v1809 client perspective, the folder location looks like //Windows10PC/SMBv2Folder, and the credentials are Windows10PC\MyMicrosoftAccountUsername + MyMicrosoftAccountPassword. Note that I'm using a Microsoft Account and not a local Windows one. These credentials work perfectly from all my Windows 10 clients.

However, I'm having great difficulty connecting to the same folder from an Ubuntu 18.10 client; I get either "Permission denied" or "Stale file handle" error messages. Can anyone tell me what the Ubuntu equivalent of the above Windows credentials are for the following SMB fields: Path, Domain (bear in mind that the PC in question is on a home LAN, NOT a domain), and Username?

Also, AFAIK I only need to have cifs-utils installed to mount an SMBv2 share. Is this the case, or should I install something additional?

Comment: You could change your Windows login settings to turn on login with local account. Yes, only cifs-utils for Linux. On the Windows host, you can choose to create a local account and grant access for this account to the share and the shared folder. On Windows, open `lusrmgr.msc` from a command line (or the run applet) to go quickly to the local users management console.

Comment: @cmak.fr Does that imply that Ubuntu doesn't support Microsoft Accounts? Also, I'm still looking for an answer as to what to put in the Path, Domain, and Username fields, Especially Path and Domain, since this isn't a domain PC.